# Injectivity of the Mellin Transform and discontinuities

Tags: integral-transforms

I am reading Stopple's *A Primer of Analytic Number Theory*. On page 234, the Mellin Transform $\mathcal{M} f$ of a function $f$ is defined as
$$\mathcal{M} f (s) = \int_1^{\infty} f(x) x^{-s - 1} dx$$

His goal is to use the injectivity of the Mellin Transform (if $\mathcal{M} f = \mathcal{M} g$ then $f = g$) to prove Von Mangoldt's Formula (also on page 234). However, one of the functions he considers has infinitely many jump discontinuities. Therefore, as far as I can see, it looks like he could have replaced it by any other function agreeing with it up to a zero measure set.

So, my question is about the nature of the injectivity of the Mellin Transform: in which sense are $f$ and $g$ equal if $\mathcal{M} f = \mathcal{M} g$?

Comment: Do you mean $\int_0^\infty$?

Comment: The book gives $\int_1^{\infty}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is implicit in what you wrote. One can define an equivalence relation $f\sim g$ if $f$ and  $g$ are  equal except on a set of measure 0, then define Mellin transform on equivalence classes instead of functions.  For context, the  book was intended for undergraduates who have  seen no more than a typical calculus sequence, certainly not measure  theory.  There are much better books for advanced students.  (I like Montgomery & Vaughan "Multiplicative Number Theory").

By the way @Brunalt is correct that typically the Mellin transform is defined as an integral from $0$ to $\infty$, not $1$ to $\infty$.  In the  book it is only  applied to functions which are  $0$ for $0\le x\le 1$, so including that in the integral only obfuscates.  For the typical reader (who is not going on to a PhD in Mathematics) this alternate definition suffices.

Comment: Thank you very much!